Querying DynamoSB GSI in Golang
I am very new to DynamoDB and highly likely missing something. I read docs and other materials but couldn't work out missing link.
I am trying to query GSI by user email but no luck so far. Do I have to create a GSI separate from the table?
This is how I create table and secondary index:
{
    "TableName": "BlogTable",
    "KeySchema": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "PK",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "SK",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "PK",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "SK",
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
            "IndexName": "BlogGlobalIndex1",
            "KeySchema": [
                {
                    "AttributeName": "PK",
                    "KeyType": "HASH"
                },
                {
                    "AttributeName": "SK",
                    "KeyType": "RANGE"
                }
            ],
            "Projection": {
                "ProjectionType": "ALL"
            },
            "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
                "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
            }
        }
    ],
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
    }
}

This is how I put items in table:
// After this I can find item by user ID.
func (d DynamoDB) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, model store.User) error {
    model.PrimaryKey = store.PrimaryKey{
        PK: "user#" + model.ID,
        SK: "user#" + model.ID,
    }

    item, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(model)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("marshal map: %w", err)
    }

    _, err = d.Client.PutItem(ctx, &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String(d.Table),
        Item:      item,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("put item: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

This is how I am trying to query GSI but it yields 0 items when looking for items by email although there are matching items. Both options below won't work.
func (d DynamoDB) FindUserByEmail(ctx context.Context, email string) (store.User, error) {
    cond1 := expression.Name("PK").Equal(expression.Value("user#" + email))
    cond2 := expression.Name("SK").Equal(expression.Value("user#" + email))
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithCondition(cond1.And(cond2)).Build()
    if err != nil {
        return store.User{}, fmt.Errorf("expression build: %w", err)
    }

    res, err := d.Client.Query(ctx, &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String(d.Table),
        IndexName: aws.String(d.GlobalIndex),

        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        FilterExpression:          expr.Filter(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.Condition(),
        ProjectionExpression:      expr.Projection(),

        // KeyConditionExpression: aws.String("PK = :PK, SK = :SK"),
        // ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
        //  "PK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "user#" + email},
        //  "SK": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: "user#" + email},
        // },
        // Limit: aws.Int32(1),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return store.User{}, fmt.Errorf("get item: %w", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res.Count) // 0
    fmt.Println(len(res.Items)) // 0

    var model store.User
// ...
    return model, nil
}

Example data fixtures:
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "SK": {
                "S": "user#1722198720607873"
            },
            "Email": {
                "S": "Shaylee54@gmail.com"
            },
            "PK": {
                "S": "user#1722198720607873"
            },
            "ID": {
                "S": "1722198720607873"
            },
            "Password": {
                "S": "5O1AMjIG8hRFeS_"
            },
            "Name": {
                "S": "Marty Ferry III"
            }
        },
        {
            "SK": {
                "S": "user#1722178078008670"
            },
            "ID": {
                "S": "1722178078008670"
            },
            "Email": {
                "S": "Carissa11@yahoo.com"
            },
            "PK": {
                "S": "user#1722178078008670"
            },
            "Name": {
                "S": "Jana Rice"
            },
            "Password": {
                "S": "OM9AfTTuwYPw_bD"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Count": 2,
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}


Can you share a sample item(s). As it's not clear if email is a different attribute then PK?

@LeeroyHannigan Added an example set now.

Answered below.

Your GSI has the same KeySchema as the table - so it's just a "replica". You'll have to define the key(s) which you want to query (Documentation).
So, if your table has a field "email", use this in the KeySchema for the GSI. Then you can query it.
"GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [{
  "IndexName": "BlogGlobalIndex1",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "email",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "SK",
                    "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  ...
}]

email has also to be added to the AttributeDefinitions.

In order to satisfy your lookup by Email you'll need to create your GSI with Email as the partition key. Then your new Query will look like the following:
func (d DynamoDB) FindUserByEmail(ctx context.Context, email string) (store.User, error) {
    cond1 := expression.Name("Email").Equal(expression.Value(email))
    expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithCondition(cond1).Build()
    if err != nil {
        return store.User{}, fmt.Errorf("expression build: %w", err)
    }

    res, err := d.Client.Query(ctx, &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String(d.Table),
        IndexName: aws.String(d.GlobalIndex),
        ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
        ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
        KeyConditionExpression:    expr.Condition(),
    })


+1 and much appreciated with your effort, thank you. I had to accept other answer as it was posted before. I have to be fair. Note: I got api error ValidationException: ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions error in your example but this works instead cond := expression.KeyEqual(expression.Key("Email"), expression.Value(email)) and expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(con).Build().
